# How to compare string variables in Jenkins `when` condition

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm defining a Jenkins declarative pipeline and having a hard time configuring a step to not execute if two strings are equal.

I've tried several things but string comparison doesn't work.

Here's my current state:

```
stages {
    stage('Check if image has changed') {
        steps {
            script {
                OLD_DIGEST = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "podman manifest inspect registry/myimage:11 2>/dev/null | jq .config.digest").trim()
                NEW_DIGEST = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "podman inspect --format='sha256:{{.Id}}' myimage:11-tmp").trim()
            }
            sh "echo previous digest:${OLD_DIGEST}, new digest:${NEW_DIGEST}"
        }
    }
    stage('Release') {
        when {
            allOf {
                expression { env.RELEASE != null && env.RELEASE == "true" }
                expression { env.OLD_DIGEST != env.NEW_DIGEST }
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh "echo Releasing image..."
            sh "podman image push myimage:11-tmp registry/myimage:11.${DATE_TIME}"
            sh "podman image push myimage:11-tmp registry/myimage:11"
        }
    }
}
```

More specifically, the issues lies in the `when`:

```
allOf {
    expression { env.RELEASE != null && env.RELEASE == "true" }
    expression { env.OLD_DIGEST != env.NEW_DIGEST }
}
```

The first expression works fine but I can't make the second work: even if `OLD_DIGEST` and `NEW_DIGEST` are different, the step is skipped.

Example output:

```
previous digest:sha256:736fd651afdffad2ee48a55a3fbab8de85552f183602d5bfedf0e74f90690e32, new digest:sha256:9003077f080f905d9b1a960b7cf933f04756df9560663196b65425beaf21203d
...
Stage "Release" skipped due to when conditional
```

---

I've also tried `expression { OLD_DIGEST != NEW_DIGEST }` (removing the `env.`) but now the result is the opposite: even when both strings are equals, the step is NOT skipped.

Output in this case:

```
previous digest:sha256:8d966d43262b818073ea23127dedb61a43963a7fafc5cffdca85141bb4aada57, new digest:sha256:8d966d43262b818073ea23127dedb61a43963a7fafc5cffdca85141bb4aada57
...
Releasing image...
```

---

I'm wondering if the issue lies in the `expression` or `allOf` at some point.

Comment: `expression { OLD_DIGEST != NEW_DIGEST }` is the correct approach, the `.env` prefix is relevant if you used it for the definition also: `env. OLD_DIGEST = sh(...`. are you sure your second condition on the `RELEASE` is working as expected? as both of them must evaluate to true in order for the stage to run.

Comment: @NoamHelmer yes, pretty sure the first condition works fine as with `expression { OLD_DIGEST != NEW_DIGEST }` I always enter the step. Even if `OLD_DIGEST` equals `NEW_DIGEST` in which case it should not.

Comment: I've updated the post with output in the case of `expression { OLD_DIGEST != NEW_DIGEST }`

Comment: @NoamHelmer has correct solution in comment as neither are pipeline environment variables, and therefore not assigned to members in the `env` object. As for the other issue: this appears to be Groovy syntax in the `expression` and therefore syntactically needs the explicit `return`: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of my issue was the output of my two strings to compare which was indeed different: one was `"xxx"` while the other was `xxx` but Jenkins output doesn't show the double quotes.

---

The correct Jenkins comparison, as stated in the comments, is `expression { OLD_DIGEST != NEW_DIGEST }` (without `env.`).

Answer (score 1):

According to my tests in the latest 2023 version, env variables are initialized on any stage, so the previous values are being overrided.

> Note: Inside **when**, the env vars has the default values, ignoring the expected values put in the previous stage. After that, in the **steps**, has the expected values(updated in the previous stage)

If you use global variables instead env variables, it works. I simulates your podman output with echo.

```
def OLD_DIGEST
def NEW_DIGEST

pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
      RELEASE = "true"
    } 
    stages {
        stage('Check if image has changed') {
            steps {
                script {
                    OLD_DIGEST = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo '1'").trim()
                    NEW_DIGEST = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo '1'").trim()
                }
                sh "echo previous digest:${OLD_DIGEST}, new digest:${NEW_DIGEST}"
            }
        }
        stage('Release') {
            when {
                allOf {
                    expression { env.RELEASE != null && env.RELEASE == "true" }
                    expression { OLD_DIGEST != NEW_DIGEST }
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh "echo Releasing image..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when OLD_DIGEST = 1 && NEW_DIGEST = 1 , the stage is skipped

[image]

if there are different, the stage is executed

[image]

Comment: Okay, so your answer works in your case but as soon as I use my shell commands it doesn't work anymore. I guess there's a special character somewhere in my strings. Will troubleshoot more.

Comment: Silly mistake on my side, one of the string actually was `"xxx"` when the other was `xxx` (without the quotes). Somehow Jenkins output is not displaying the quotes.

Comment: It works without the `def` as well.